# Linking To Several Pixels Before A Div On the Same Page

Tags: html, hyperlink, css-position

This is probably a really simple question. I have a link on the page [tsawebmaster1.hhstsa.com/web_design.html](http://tsawebmaster1.hhstsa.com/web_design.html) that links to a div on the same page as the link itself using [tsawebmaster1.hhstsa.com/web_design.html#seven_steps](http://tsawebmaster1.hhstsa.com/web_design.html#seven_steps) and it works just fine. The problem is that my fixed header is at the top of the page and thus overlaps the content by 100px, so when it takes you to that div, the user does not see the top of the div linked to. Is there a way I can link 100px less than a certain div.

Answer (score 0):

You better use javascript to reach your goal. the window.scrollTo(x,y) function can make your page scroll to a specified amount of pixels on click (also it will look much more neat).
documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.scrollTo

usage:

```
     <a href="#" onClick="window.scrollTo(0, 100);">click to scroll down 100 pixels</a>
```

Comment: Since it's JavaScript, should that be within <script> tags or do I just put that as is directly into the HTML?

Comment: just as shown. or you can do <a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.scrollTo(0,100);">...  No need for script tags

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work but you should try this:

Our seven core steps to web design will teach you the simple steps on how a website is built. Before delving into any new topic, it is important to develop background knowledge of the whole picture. This way, when you start actually learning web design in depth, you'll be able to connect your under

Try put an empty paragraph between your logo and the contents.